# Task scheduler Application and Focus

Tags: windows-7

I need to run a task using the scheduler, the problem is that, if I double click on the executable, the program gets the focus and run in full screen, if I run the same executable using task scheduler, the command window remains on top and the application runs on the background, can please somebody help me?

cheers

Comment: It seems I did resolve the issue but I can't answer my own questions yet !

Comment: I will write what it seems an apparent solution later.

Answer (score 8):

This is probably a bit late for you but I ran into the same problem with Google chrome not receiving focus when started by task scheduler, and this is how I fixed it:

Start Program field: `C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe`
Argument field: `/c start "" "C:\Program Files\Chrome\Chrome.exe" --some-arguments`

This will basically open up `cmd.exe` and pass the arguments to it, because `/c` is specified it will run those arguments and then close.

Since `start` will give anything started with it focus, chrome comes up with its window focused.

Have fun.

Answer (score 1):

I did manage to revolve the problem with a vbs script running my executable instead of running the executable directly from the task scheduler.
So now the task scheduler runs my vbs script that runs the executable.